# Calculate a multiple sum of inverse integers.

Tags: summation

The question is to calculate a following sum:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal S}_p(n) :=\sum\limits_{1\le j_1 < j_2 < \dots <j_p \le n-1} \prod\limits_{q=1}^p \frac{1}{n-j_q}
\end{equation}
for $p=1,2,..$ and $n\ge 1$.
From purely combinatorial reasoning we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal S}_1(n) &=& H_{n-1} \\
{\mathcal S}_2(n) &=& \frac{1}{2!} \left(H_{n-1}^2 - H^{(2)}_{n-1} \right) \\
{\mathcal S}_3(n) &=& \frac{1}{3!} \left(H_{n-1}^3 - 3 H_{n-1} H_{n-1}^{(2)} + 2 H_{n-1}^{(3)}\right) \\
{\mathcal S}_4(n) &=& \frac{1}{4!} \left(H^4_{n-1} - 6 H_{n-1}^2 H_{n-1}^{(2)} + 8 H_{n-1} H_{n-1}^{(3)} + 3 H_{n-1}^{(2)} H_{n-1}^{(2)} - 6 H_{n-1}^{(4)}\right) \\
{\mathcal S}_5(n) &=& \frac{1}{5!} \left(H_{n-1}^5 - 10 H_{n-1}^3 H_{n-1}^{(2)} + 20 H_{n-1}^2 H_{n-1}^{(3)} + 15 H_{n-1} ((H_{n-1}^{(2)})^2 - 2 H_{n-1}^{(4)}) - 20 H_{n-1}^{(2)} H_{n-1}^{(3)}  + 24 H_{n-1}^{(5)}\right) \\
{\mathcal S}_6(n) &=& \frac{1}{6!} \left(H_{n-1}^6 - 15 H_{n-1}^4 H_{n-1}^{(2)} + 40 H_{n-1}^3 H_{n-1}^{(3)} + 45 H_{n-1}^2 ((H_{n-1}^{(2)})^2 - 2 H_{n-1}^{(4)}) - 
 24 H_{n-1} (5 H_{n-1}^{(2)} H_{n-1}^{(3)} - 6 H_{n-1}^{(5)}) + 5 (-3 (H_{n-1}^{(2)})^3 + 18 H_{n-1}^{(2)} H_{n-1}^{(4)} + 8 ((H_{n-1}^{(3)})^2 - 3 H_{n-1}^{(6)}) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $H_{n-1}^{(r)} := \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} 1/j^r$ is the generalised Harmonic number.

Is it possible to find the result for generic $p\ge 1$?

Comment: No idea how to get a compact expression for $\mathcal{S}_p(n)$ in general. However, we have
$$1 + \sum_{p=1}^{n-1} \mathcal{S}_p(n) z^p 
= \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 + \frac{z}{n-k}\right)
= \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 + \frac{z}{k}\right)
= \exp\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)\right]
= \exp\left[\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^p}\right)z^p\right]
= \exp\left[\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{p-1} H_{n-1}^{(p)}}{p} z^p\right]
$$
and you can expand the RHS as a formal power series in $z$ to obtain expression for other $\mathcal{S}_p(n)$.

Comment: See the sequence A181897 in OEIS

Answer (score 1):

Start with
$$1 + \sum_{p=1}^{n-1} \mathcal{S}_p(n) z^p 
= \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 + \frac{z}{n-k}\right)
= \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 + \frac{z}{k}\right)
= \exp\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)\right]
= \exp\left[\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^p}\right)z^p\right]
= \exp\left[\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{p-1} H_{n-1}^{(p)}}{p} z^p\right]$$
Taking logarithm and apply $z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ on both sides, we get

$$\sum_{p=1}^{n-1}p\mathcal{S}_p(n) z^p
= \left(\sum_{p=1}^\infty (-1)^{p-1} H_{n-1}^{p} z^p\right)
\left(1 + \sum_{p=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{S}_p(n) z^p\right)
$$
Expanding both sides and compare coefficients of $z^p$, we obtain a chain of identities:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}_1(n) &= H_{n-1}\\
2\,\mathcal{S}_2(n) &= H_{n-1} \mathcal{S}_1(n) - H_{n-1}^{(2)}\\
3\,\mathcal{S}_3(n) &= H_{n-1} \mathcal{S}_2(n) - H_{n-1}^{(2)}\mathcal{S}_1(n) + H_{n-1}^{(3)}\\
4\,\mathcal{S}_4(n) &= H_{n-1} \mathcal{S}_3(n) - H_{n-1}^{(2)}\mathcal{S}_2(n) + H_{n-1}^{(3)}\mathcal{S}_1(n) - H_{n-1}^{(4)}\\
&\;\vdots\\
p\,\mathcal{S}_p(n) &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1} H_{n-1}^{(k)} \mathcal{S}_{p-k}(n)\right)
+ (-1)^{p-1} H_{n-1}^{(p)}
\end{align}$$

This is the [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) associated with the set of numbers $\;\displaystyle \frac{1}{n-j}\;$ for $1 \le j \le n-1$. One can use it to obtain the expression of $\mathcal{S}_p$ for higher $p$ recursively.
Let $h_p = H_{n-1}^{(p)}$, following are some more $\mathcal{S}_p$ computed by this approach.
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
6!\mathcal{S}_{6}(n) &=& -120{h}_{6}+144{h}_{1}{h}_{5}+90{h}_{2}{h}_{4}-90{h}_{1}^{2}{h}_{4}+40{h}_{3}^{2}-120{h}_{1}{h}_{2}{h}_{3}\\
&&+40{h}_{1}^{3}{h}_{3}-15{h}_{2}^{3}+45{h}_{1}^{2}{h}_{2}^{2}-15{h}_{1}^{4}{h}_{2}+{h}_{1}^{6}\\
7!\mathcal{S}_{7}(n) &=& 720{h}_{7}-840{h}_{1}{h}_{6}-504{h}_{2}{h}_{5}+504{h}_{1}^{2}{h}_{5}-420{h}_{3}{h}_{4}+630{h}_{1}{h}_{2}{h}_{4}\\
&&-210{h}_{1}^{3}{h}_{4}+280{h}_{1}{h}_{3}^{2}+210{h}_{2}^{2}{h}_{3}-420{h}_{1}^{2}{h}_{2}{h}_{3}\\
&&+70{h}_{1}^{4}{h}_{3}-105{h}_{1}{h}_{2}^{3}+105{h}_{1}^{3}{h}_{2}^{2}-21{h}_{1}^{5}{h}_{2}+{h}_{1}^{7}\\
8!\mathcal{S}_{8}(n) &=& -5040{h}_{8}+5760{h}_{1}{h}_{7}+3360{h}_{2}{h}_{6}-3360{h}_{1}^{2}{h}_{6}+2688{h}_{3}{h}_{5}\\
&&-4032{h}_{1}{h}_{2}{h}_{5}+1344{h}_{1}^{3}{h}_{5}+1260{h}_{4}^{2}-3360{h}_{1}{h}_{3}{h}_{4}\\
&&-1260{h}_{2}^{2}{h}_{4}+2520{h}_{1}^{2}{h}_{2}{h}_{4}-420{h}_{1}^{4}{h}_{4}-1120{h}_{2}{h}_{3}^{2}\\
&&+1120{h}_{1}^{2}{h}_{3}^{2}+1680{h}_{1}{h}_{2}^{2}{h}_{3}-1120{h}_{1}^{3}{h}_{2}{h}_{3}+112{h}_{1}^{5}{h}_{3}\\
&&+105{h}_{2}^{4}-420{h}_{1}^{2}{h}_{2}^{3}+210{h}_{1}^{4}{h}_{2}^{2}-28{h}_{1}^{6}{h}_{2}+{h}_{1}^{8}\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the right hand side of the identity given by achille hui  we get ``a compact'' expression for the sum:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal S}_p(n) &=& \sum\limits_{m=1}^p \frac{(-1)^{-m+p} }{m!} \sum\limits_{p_1+p_2+\dots+p_m=p} \prod\limits_{q=1}^m \frac{H_{n-1}^{(p_q)}}{p_q} \\
&=& \frac{1}{1!} \frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p} H^{(p)}_{n-1} + \frac{(-1)^{p-2}}{2!} \sum\limits_{p_1=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{p_1 (p-p_1)} H_{n-1}^{(p_1)} H_{n-1}^{(p-p_1)} + \dots + \frac{1}{p!} H_{n-1}^p
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we seek to evaluate

$$S_n(m) = \sum_{1\le j_1 \lt j_2 \lt\cdots\lt j_n \le m-1}
\prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{m-j_q}.$$

By way of enrichment let me point  out that we can express this sum in
terms  of the  cycle  index  $Z(P_n)$ of  the  unlabeled set  operator
$\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$ by applying the Polya Enumeration Theorem.

Recall  the recurrence by Lovasz  for the cycle  index $Z(P_n)$ of
the set operator $\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$ on $n$ slots, which is
$$Z(P_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n (-1)^{l-1} a_l Z(P_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(P_0) = 1.$$
This recurrence lets us calculate the cycle index $Z(P_n)$ very easily.

The sum is then given by
$$Z(P_n)(Q_1+Q_2+\cdots+Q_{m-1})$$
evaluated at $Q_k = \frac{1}{m-k}.$

The Polya enumeration rule says to substitute as follows:
$$a_l = Q_1^l + Q_2^l + \cdots + Q_{m-1}^l$$

in other words
$$a_l = H_{m-1}^{(l)}$$

for a final answer of 
$${\large
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ \left.Z(P_n)\right|_{a_l = H_{m-1}^{(l)}}}}$$

For example we have
$$Z(P_5) = \frac{1}{5!}
\left({a_{{1}}}^{5}-10\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{3}+20\,a_{{3}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}
+15\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}-30\,a_{{4}}a_{{1}}
-20\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}+24\,a_{{5}}\right)$$
and the substitution should now be clear.